# Xcode: git commit disappeared

Tags: xcode, git

I am working on Xcode IDE and I have been committed every time some major changes have made in my codes.
Then I realized that in "Branches" directory, I am currently at any of the branch. Therefore, the commits I made so far did not reflect in any of my Branches.

Where can I find the committed versions...?

I was making commit when (current) was not displayed.

---

Okay so I found my lost commit.

Comment: I have never used xcode, but if the directory is just a regular git repo then you should be able to use various terminal commands (like `git reflog`) to find missing commits.

Comment: Yes, it works as normal fit. I checked git reflog but I saw any change from today... But im 100% sure commit was made successfully for not returning errors when i commited..

Comment: I tried gitk --all but i dont see and commit from today... What is going on

Comment: switch to the branch you committed. Hope you'll get there

Comment: Okay, so I found my lost commit and seems like I dont belong to any of the branches... How can I bring APIIntegration reference(head) to most updated commit?

Comment: Okay, i was able to change branch pointer to head. Thank you for all the help. I feel much better now :D

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem: my working branch was called "GraphicsAndMedia", but I had to go back to a previous commit, so I checked out an older commit. I carried on working from this older commit forgetting that I was really in detached head mode. At some point later, I couldn't find anymore these commits. Below is what I've done to have them back and on a new working branch.

@JDB's suggestion of **`git reflog`** seems the right track to find a "lost commit", such as this one I had.
Here are the steps to find and restore it:

1. Run
   `git reflog`
   command, which gives a history of what's been done (see picture, orange ellipse).
   [image]

2. Find the lost commit (see highlighted commit) and use git command:
   `git checkout 52572b6...`
   (this is the detached head that got lost somehow - you will need to change this number to whatever commit number you found)
3. Reattach this lost commit as a proper branch, with:
   `git switch -c <new-branch-name>`
   for switching, and creating, a new branch out of this lost and checked out (step 2) commit.
4. Back to Xcode, all lost commits should now be restored and visible.